# Difference between users created through cryptogen and enrolled through Fabric CA Server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

While doing Hyperledger fabric setup, we create crypto material and mention users for organizations and and correspondingly user crypto material gets generated which is used to invoke chaincode while logging through CLI. Also, when we try to connect network through SDK we also need to enroll and register user to connect to network. So, what is the difference between these two users?

Answer (score 3):

Cryptogen utility used for generating Hyperledger Fabric key material is mainly meant to be used for testing environment only.

It generates the CA certificate before the Fabric CA Server is up. {This won't be the case in production env.}

This certificate is mounted to fabric-ca in *docker-compose.yaml* file. This is done via *volumes* keyword as in the below snippet:

`ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/4239aa0dcd76daeeb8ba0cda701851d14504d31aad1b2ddddbac6a57365e497c_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic`

The command 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d' in above script registers a bootstrap identity. This bootstrap identity is used by the application to enroll the 'admin' user. During this enrollment, fabric-ca-server gives the app a ecert, users private key and cacert chain PEM files.

**From the above reference, the users certs generated by cryptogen and via application will be issued using the same root CA Cert.**

When using CLI to execute commands such install chaincode, instantiate chaincode etc. you will be using the user certs generated by the cryptogen as these are mounted into the corresponding peer. Again refer to the *volumes* section of peer in *docker-compose.yaml* for this:

```
volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
```

Comment: To conclude, there is no difference between application users used for calling REST API given by SDK and users created via cryptogen and used with CLI, except the ways they are being created is different.

Comment: "to be used for testing environment only", does it mean we should generate crypto materials for the network topology using Fabric-CA?

Comment: @edwardaa Yes, for the cert and key consistency and persistency, we should use fabric-ca and others system like LDAP to manage them in product.