# Assigning peer context for a Hyperledger Fabric web application

Tags: node.js, web-applications, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

**Disclaimer:** I have no prior experience in software development whatsoever and am tasked to develop a blockchain application since 4 months ago. Please forgive my lack of knowledge regarding most thing.

I am currently building a web application to interact with Hyperledger Fabric. I have managed to spin up docker containers for the peer, orderer nodes etc, each defined in the connection profile, with their own localhost ports.

I am also developing a simple front end and server side restAPI on the get go and has achieved functionality that allows the user to login and have their user context set and perform some application specific function.

For the Blockchain aspect of the project, I am trying to modify the "balance transfer" (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/app.js) example in the fabric sample for my use case.

So far, I have managed to establish the "Channel Creation" endpoint to allow an administrator on the web application to perform channel creation through the use Hyperledger fabric SDK by uploading the channel.tx file.

But I am lost when I have to join the peers to the channel. The fabric sample example has the following code.

```
// Join Channel
app.post('/channels/:channelName/peers', async function(req, res) {
    logger.info('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< J O I N  C H A N N E L >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
    var channelName = req.params.channelName;
    var peers = req.body.peers;
    logger.debug('channelName : ' + channelName);
    logger.debug('peers : ' + peers);
    logger.debug('username :' + req.username);
    logger.debug('orgname:' + req.orgname);

    if (!channelName) {
        res.json(getErrorMessage('\'channelName\''));
        return;
    }
    if (!peers || peers.length == 0) {
        res.json(getErrorMessage('\'peers\''));
        return;
    }

    let message =  await join.joinChannel(channelName, peers, req.username, req.orgname);
    res.send(message);
});
```

According to a snippet from the testAPI.sh script
(https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/testAPIs.sh)

```
echo "POST request Join channel on Org1"
echo
curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/peers \
  -H "authorization: Bearer $ORG1_TOKEN" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com","peer1.org1.example.com"]
}'
echo
echo

echo "POST request Join channel on Org2"
echo
curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/peers \
  -H "authorization: Bearer $ORG2_TOKEN" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "peers": ["peer0.org2.example.com","peer1.org2.example.com"]
}'
echo
echo
```

It seems that the peer names (which have to be specified in the connection profile) are provided as request to join the peers to the channel. Which does not quite make sense to me, since I envision peers to be like "users of different IP" accessing the web application. Specifying which peers to join the channel by providing their connection profile reference name appears to be a static (hard-coded, non-dynamic) approach.

**What I do not understand is: How can I assign the authenticated user to their individual peer context, and with their own peer context set on the web application, the users are able to join the channel on their own?**

The fabric tutorials only perform the switching of peer context through CLI, and join the peers to channel through CLI as well.
`CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer channel join -b mychannel.block`

**How can I achieve switching of peer context through the Hyperledger Fabric SDK? or even 1 peer context to 1 authenticated user, and logging in as another user will mean that the peer context is changed to the other user that is currently authenticated.**

I can't seem to wrap my head around what is a peer in physical sense in such a decentralized setup. Please provide detailed and laymen explanation for me to understand the concept as much as possible. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

think of the blockchain network, as a backend database(ledger DB) that your web application (remote, in a network IP context, to the peers that write to the ledger) needs to interact with. What your application needs to know is: - what is the connection info (profile), how do I connect, what is the smart contract to interact with, and what transaction function(s) (in that contract) do I want to invoke, to write to the ledger (or query, to read etc).

The balance transfer app is largely a sample application/exercise in using the Fabric SDK to demonstrate (programatically) basic functionalities of a H/Fabric blockchain network, such as creating channel(s), installing chaincode (smart contract) , instantiating chaincode , invoking chaincode and querying chaincode.

Your web application wants to interact with your running Fabric blockchain network (backend). So with that, I suggest to look at the following resources to get a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

1) Read the documentation at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html to grasp the concepts and read the logical flow of the writing your first application using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 new programming model (designed to make writing apps easier without having to have specialist 'blockchain' dev knowledge).

2) Try out the sample Fabcar application as introduced here (elements include the contract, the network, and the SDK APIs interacting (eg. submit txns, query the ledger) with the contract deployed to the peers) -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/understand_fabcar_network.html . The actual Fabcar sample app is here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/fabcar  (and the connection profile provided, connects to the Fabric BYFN network 'stood up' using `startFabric.sh` there).

3) Once your web application is able to interact (without application level authentication initially), you can proceed to implement your authentication strategy of choice for your web app/front end. Once authenticated in your app, the application users use wallets (containing an X509 cert/key combo) to interact with the blockchain. This sample out on Github https://github.com/IBM/build-blockchain-insurance-app should assist you with understanding the app architecture and what components belong where.

Comment: Thank you answering, will revisit the items you put together. I went through them when I started out clueless everything from basic scripting, programming, server, api, sdk etc. So I probably forgot much of it by now after giving myself quite abit of crash course on web development, or I might not have appreciated the tutorials properly back then. Will post any further questions that I still cannot figure out by then.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not getting the peer part. If I would like to act as a peer e.g. peer0 of Org1 (As specified in the connection profile), to invoke a chaincode transaction. How can I change the peer context to e.g. peer1 of Org2 (Also specified in the connection profile) to query the ledger? Without the use of the CLI? Because If I want to demonstrate the application, I have to switch the peer context (i.e. accessing this remote web application on different machines to interact with the blockchain) that is essentially a huge reason for my confusion.

Comment: Or, how exactly do I go about setting up a machine/device/user account as a peer? So that all interaction from that machine will allow the user to be the specific peer that it was assigned to be.

Comment: the web application users (eg.via a common connection profile) in an org will submit a transaction through a peer connection. The transaction gets sent to other endorsing peers (some of which could be other orgs' peers) but that is Hyperledger Fabric's responsibility, not the application.

Comment: I suggest to read the mechanics https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html (in the example it describes (app) client A & B (eg different org clients). Ultimately, the user (via client application) simply submits a transaction to the Fabric network (eg, via APIs etc), and the configured Fabric network will handle the rest. If your app needs to use a different peer (like is the case for different orgs), they will simply use different connection info.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand slightly better now after revisiting the documents. But sidetrack a little, I revisited the commercial paper tutorial and have questions on identity generation. The exposed APIs from the SDK to create an identity in a user specified wallet requires the crypto material (public & priv key) for that specific organisation user. Which I believe is generated through the use of the cryptogen cli tool. Since the cryptogen consumes the configtx.yaml (statically defined), is there anyway we can dynamically create identity through the SDK without involving the cryptogen cli?

Comment: hi - yes. Use the SDK (sample [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/registerUser.js)  or the CLI [here](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/clientcli.html) or use a 3rd party CA if required etc  to have your CA issue identities (eg. register, enrol, and then get cert/key combo to import to a user wallet). Cryptogen is used to bootstrap identities for testing purposes [see answer  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131847/difference-between-users-created-through-cryptogen-and-enrolled-through-fabric-c).